# checked doesn't exist on HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Please, I don't know why this is not working. It's practically telling me that "checked" doesn't exist on the input element.

```
interface RadioProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg";
}

const RadioInput = (props: RadioProps) => <Wrapper size={size}>
  <input id={id} {...props} type="radio" />
  <label htmlFor={props.id || id} size={size}></Label>
</Wrapper>

const App = () => <RadioInput checked={checked} />

// Error: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RadioProps'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
```

you can use

```
React.DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>
```

in this case, your custom interface for your component will be like this

```
    interface RadioProps extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement> {
        size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, although now it's clashing with the "size" ('"xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg"' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'), but I could update that.